# Do we need [programmatically-created]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[programmatically-created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmatically-created) seems to refer to UI. Only around 100 questions. I don't think it adds anything to questions.

Comment: It seems like a useful concept.  Too bad the tag isn't more descriptive.

Comment: It sounds to vague to ever be a useful tag.